# Bash parameter expansion can't match spaces in variables like $* and $@

Tags: bash, shell, parameter-expansion

Using dash (0.5.10.2), I can do this:

```sh
% dash
$ set -- x hello world
$ echo "<${*#x }>"
<hello world>
```

This is the behavior I expect. The contents of `$*` (which are `x hello world` as assigned by `set` and delimited by spaces) are run through shell [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to remove any leading `x`  for echo, thus resulting in `hello world`, which I'm echoing with surrounding brackets to demonstrate the lack of surrounding white space.

I can't replicate that in bash (5.0.2(1)-release). It appears the space, a delimiter, is inaccessible:

```sh
% bash
$ set -- x hello world
$ echo "<${*#x }>"
<x hello world>
$ echo "<${@#x }>"     # trying $@ instead of $*
<x hello world>
$ echo "<${*#x}>"      # without the space works but now I have a space
< hello world>
$ echo "<${*#x?}>"     # trying the `?` wildcard for a single character
<x hello world>
$ echo "<${*#x\ }>"    # trying to escape the space
<x hello world>
$ echo "<${*/#x /}>"   # using bash pattern substitution instead
<x hello world>
$ echo "<${*#x$IFS}>"  # trying the input field separator variable
<x hello world>
```

Is there a solution here? Perhaps some way of modifying `$*` or changing the output field separator?

My current workaround is to assign it to a temporary variable, but that's pretty ugly. (I need bash or else I'd stick with /bin/sh, which is dash.)

Comment: As I read http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02: *If parameter is `#`, `*`, or `@`, the result of the expansion is unspecified.* -- so both are equally correct, and a script that wants to work on all POSIX platforms shouldn't rely on either behavior. (`var=$*` and `${var// /<SPACE>}`, and you're set).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Err... Um.. isn't `${var// /<SPACE>}` *parameter expansion with substring replacement* .. a bashism? POSIX only provides *suffix* and *prefix* removal as I read it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, quite right. Still, the point that `var=$*` avoids relying on undefined behavior stands.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin – This is a bash question, so the bashism is okay ... though I was using `var="$*"; echo "${var#x }"` to the same effect because I so rarely script in bash and I try to limit my bash scripts' bashisms to where they're absolutely necessary.

Comment: Agreed, I was just confused by your apparent use of `dash`.

Comment: If you just want to discard the first argument before concatenating those that remain, `shift` is your friend; to avoid changing `$1`, you can scope it to a function: `myfunc() { shift; printf '%s\n' "$*"; }; concatenationOfAllArgsButTheFirst=$(myfunc "$@")"` leaves the original value of `"$@"` alone.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy – If I didn't care about preserving that array, I could indeed `shift`. The function is a bit unwieldy in the face of that other guy's more elegant (bashism) `${*:2}` (see the comment to his answer).

Comment: Yes, I'd definitely suggest the bashism if portability isn't a priority.

Comment: This whole mess started when I had to ~upgrade my script from /bin/sh (dash) to bash just for `read -t` to allow easier skipping of a `sleep` call. (This should answer @DavidC.Rankin's confusion.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For array-like operands, the string operation is applied *for each* element *before* they are joined on spaces. Therefore, you can't apply them to the joining space.

Here's an example showing this:

```
$ set -- hello world "hello world with spaces"
$ echo "${*// /<SPACE>}"
hello world hello<SPACE>world<SPACE>with<SPACE>spaces
```

Spaces within each argument is replaced just fine, but the spaces between them as inserted by `$*` are not affected.

The workaround is indeed a temporary variable.

Comment: Ah, nice demonstration. `echo "<${*#hello }>"` (using your `set` line) better fits what I'm doing, and sure enough it gives me `<hello world world with spaces>` because of the implicit _for each_ that you noted.

Comment: If your real question is "How do I concatenate all arguments except the first one?" then the answer is `"${*:2}"`

Comment: Actually, yes: that's the literal answer to my (oversimplified) question, though I think your first paragraph and Charles Duffy's comment to the question combine for a more informative answer. (Also, I had a whole bunch of conditionals like `[ "$*" != "${*#* foo* bar}" ]` which I've had to convert to `case` patterns like `( *\ foo*\ bar* )` but that didn't make it to the simplified question I asked here.)